# strange ssms results about t-sql SUM func, couldn't figure out

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I am learning t-sql window function when found something strange, here is the normal code, very simple.
[image]

then I tried delete the window frame clause and got the same results.
[image]

anyone can explain why the result of the second one, thanks.

Comment: Because of column `ordermonth` doesn't have a duplicate or repeated months (i.e. `1,2,3, . . `) if so, then second one is enough no need to use `UNBOUNDED PRECEDING. . .`.

Comment: Why would you take a screenshot of code instead of copy/pasting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second query returns the same results, because "range between unbounded preceding and current row" is the default frame, as you can see in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#important) and there are no duplicated rows in your table (i.e. multiple rows with the same empid and ordermonth).

> If ROWS/RANGE is not specified but ORDER BY is specified, RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW is used as default for window frame.